# GUI elements not reacting to changes in properties

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, binding, properties

I've created a property of type bool in my app delegate:

in AppDelegate.h:

```
@property(assign) BOOL myProp;
```

in AppDelegate.m:

```
@synthesize myProp;
```

Then in the XIB file I've opened the binding editor for a button's Enabled-property.
I've enabled the binding and set it to "App Delegate". For the model key path I chose:

> self.myProp

When I run the application and toggle the value of my property nothing happens. The button does not change its enable-state. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign to the property, do you do it via `self.myProp = foo` or `myProp = foo`?  The latter is using direct ivar access, which bypasses [KVO](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-BAJEAIEE) (Key-Value Observing, a foundation component of Bindings).  You can [manually trigger KVO notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-SW3), but the better option is almost always to just assign via the setter method (as self. does) and get [automatic change notification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-SW1) implicitly.

Note that in order to have it generate a setter you will need to privately redeclare your property as readwrite, which you can do using a [class extension](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW19).

Comment: `readwrite` is default for setters (so you don't need to write it explicitly)

Answer (score 1):

First it should be declared as BOOL, second you have declared it as readonly (if you want to change the value you have to remove readonly)

To set the BOOL you use `self.myProp = YES/NO;`

Comment: Thanks, but that did not fix the problem :-(

Comment: Then you need to provide more info about your problem, what is expected output and what actually happens. Logs and code...

Comment: There isn't any more relevant code. All I do is call "myProp = !myProp" once in a while to toggle its value. The button bound this property does NOT change is state...

Comment: How is the button "bound" to this property?

Comment: I went to the XIB-editor (formerly interface builder?) and selected the button. I then went to the bindings tab and expanded the section for the button's enabled property. Here I enabled the binding and set it to "App Delegate". For the model key path I chose "self.myProp", as suggested by the auto completion.

Comment: @Boris `myProp =! myProp` will **not** work since you're bypassing KVC/KVO (you are directly setting the ivar without using an accessor). Peter is right, you should `self.myProp =! self.myProp` instead.

Answer (score 1):

[image]I tried to solve this in this way

In AppDelegate.h

```
@property (assign)BOOL myProp;
- (IBAction)onOff:(id)sender; //to switch the value of myProp
```

In AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize myProp;

- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        myProp=NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)onOff:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"before myProp=%d",myProp);
    self.myProp=!myProp;
    NSLog(@"after myProp=%d",myProp);

}
```

The target button's Enabled is set to App Delegate.

Model Key Path is set to self.myProp

And its done !!!